# Agile Web Development with Rails 4: MiniTest error for Update action in line_items_controller_test.rb

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, fixtures, minitest

I'm a beginner working my way through *Agile Web Development with Rails 4* where we (readers) build a shopping-cart style demo app. So, far the main REST resources are 1) products, 2) carts and 3) line items. This is my second demo/sample app on my path to learning Rails and everything seems straight-forward so far, except I'm consistently getting an error in my tests for the *update* action in the line items controller. I'm not sure whether it's an error related to the test itself, the actual controller action, and/or my fixtures settings. (I'm using the "built-in" MiniTest with fixtures for the first time; previous sample app I did used RSpec and FactoryGirl.)

The error (not failure) I'm getting looks like this:

```
Finished tests in 0.936959s, 26.6821 tests/s, 56.5660 assertions/s.

  1) Error:
LineItemsControllerTest#test_should_update_line_item:
ActionController::ActionControllerError: Cannot redirect to nil!
    app/controllers/line_items_controller.rb:54:in `block (2 levels) in update'
    app/controllers/line_items_controller.rb:52:in `update'
    test/controllers/line_items_controller_test.rb:38:in `block in <class:LineItemsControllerTest>'

25 tests, 53 assertions, 0 failures, 1 errors, 0 skips
```

I'm unclear why I'm redirecting to nil. Is the path bad? Or is it the object at the end of the path? And/or "other"?  I don't readily see anything in the controller itself that looks like a problem (regardless, I've included the code below), so I suspect it has something to do with the test file or fixtures settings. I've tried filling in various 'dummy' (e.g., `product_id: 55`) and 'referenced' (e.g., `product_id: products(:ruby).id`) values in the line_items.yml fixtures with no success.

I've also tried different things within the controller test *setup*, such as referencing specific fixture IDs in other fixture types (products and carts) that line items belong to (same idea as above). I tried editing the update test in a number of ways as well, including trying a redirect to the line item's cart instead of the line_items_path, such as:

```
assert_redirected_to cart_path(assigns(:line_item).cart)
```

...instead of...

```
assert_redirected_to line_item_path(assigns(:line_item))
```

Also tried variations of defining :line_item, which I take to be the updated object, e.g.:

```
patch :update, id: @line_item, line_item: { product_id: products(:ruby).id }
```

...instead of...

```
patch :update, id: @line_item, line_item: { product_id: @line_item.product_id }
```

What I believe to be relevant code included below. Any help very much appreciated!

**line_items_controller.rb**

```
class LineItemsController < ApplicationController
  include CurrentCart
  before_action :set_cart, only: [:create]
  before_action :set_line_item, only: [:show, :edit, :update, :destroy]


  # GET /line_items
  # GET /line_items.json
  def index
    @line_items = LineItem.all
  end

  # GET /line_items/1
  # GET /line_items/1.json
  def show
  end

  # GET /line_items/new
  def new
    @line_item = LineItem.new
  end

  # GET /line_items/1/edit
  def edit
  end

  # POST /line_items
  # POST /line_items.json
  def create
    product = Product.find(params[:product_id])
    @line_item = @cart.add_product(product.id)

    respond_to do |format|
      if @line_item.save
        format.html { redirect_to @line_item.cart,
          notice: 'Line item was successfully created.' }
        format.json { render action: 'show',
          status: :created, location: @line_item }
      else
        format.html { render action: 'new' }
        format.json { render json: @line_item.errors,
          status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end

    session[:count] = nil
  end

  # PATCH/PUT /line_items/1
  # PATCH/PUT /line_items/1.json
  def update
    respond_to do |format|
      if @line_item.update(line_item_params)
        format.html { redirect_to @line_item.cart,
          notice: 'Line item was successfully updated.' }
        format.json { head :no_content }
      else
        format.html { render action: 'edit' }
        format.json { render json: @line_item.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end

  # DELETE /line_items/1
  # DELETE /line_items/1.json
  def destroy
    @line_item.destroy
    respond_to do |format|
      format.html { redirect_to line_items_url }
      format.json { head :no_content }
    end
  end

  private
    # Use callbacks to share common setup or constraints between actions.
    def set_line_item
      @line_item = LineItem.find(params[:id])
    end

    # Never trust parameters from the scary internet, only allow the white list through.
    def line_item_params
      params.require(:line_item).permit(:product_id)
    end
end
```

**line_items_controller_test.rb**

```
require 'test_helper'

class LineItemsControllerTest < ActionController::TestCase
  setup do
    @line_item = line_items(:one)
  end

  test "should get index" do
    get :index
    assert_response :success
    assert_not_nil assigns(:line_items)
  end

  test "should get new" do
    get :new
    assert_response :success
  end

  test "should create line_item" do
    assert_difference('LineItem.count') do
      post :create, product_id: products(:ruby).id 
    end

    assert_redirected_to cart_path(assigns(:line_item).cart)
  end

  test "should show line_item" do
    get :show, id: @line_item
    assert_response :success
  end

  test "should get edit" do
    get :edit, id: @line_item
    assert_response :success
  end

  test "should update line_item" do
    patch :update, id: @line_item, line_item: { product_id: @line_item.product_id }
    assert_redirected_to line_item_path(assigns(:line_item))
  end

  test "should destroy line_item" do
    assert_difference('LineItem.count', -1) do
      delete :destroy, id: @line_item
    end

    assert_redirected_to line_items_path
  end
end
```

**line_items.yml**

```
one:
  product_id: #Trying values here doesn't seem to help.
  cart_id: #Trying values here doesn't seem to help.

two:
  product_id: 
  cart_id:
```

**products.yml**

```
one:
  title: MyString
  description: MyText
  image_url: MyString
  price: 9.99

two:
  title: MyString
  description: MyText
  image_url: MyString
  price: 9.99

ruby:
  title:        Programming Ruby 1.9
  description:
    Ruby is the fastest growing and most exicting dynamic
    language out there. If you need to get working programs
    delivered fast, you should add Ruby to your toolbox.
  price:        49.50
  image_url:    ruby.png

three:
  title: MyString
  description: MyText
  image_url: MyString
  price: 9.99
```

**carts.yml**

```
one: {}
# column: value
#
two: {}
#  column: value
```

Answer (score 1):

In `line_items_controller.rb` you redirect back to the cart page using the Rails resource notation.  The line item in question is `:one` which has no associated cart.  Try assigning one by modifying `line_item.yml` like so:

```
one:
  product: one
  cart: one
```

I *think* Rails should be smart enough to know that you want `Product` and `Cart`, respectively, for these assignments, but if not, you might try using more descriptive / unique labels for your fixtures: `:cart_one`, `:product_one` or even `:joes_cart`, `:bobs_cart`, etc.

Answer (score 0):

You're line item has no id in line_items.yml. Make it like this

**line_item.yml**

```
one:
  id: 1
  product_id: #Trying values here doesn't seem to help.
  cart_id: #Trying values here doesn't seem to help.

two:
  id: 2
  product_id: 
  cart_id:
```

You're also trying to pass the entire object instead of the id in the tests. Just pass the id :

```
patch :update, id: @line_item.id, line_item: { product_id: @line_item.product_id }
```

You shouldn't really be trying to post the entire object ever. Post the object id instead

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply! Ah, upon first reading your answer I was convinced that was the problem ... then I tried it and ... same (error) story.